# Sum a colum of data and add result to a new column

Tags: sql, ssms

I want to sum the column of extended_price and put the values into a new column to the right as 'total', but doing this creates an error :

> Column 'P21.dbo.invoice_hdr.customer_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Expected Outcome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDH76.png)

The code I tried :

```sql
    SELECT customer_id AS CustomerID
    , invoice_date AS InvoiceDate
    , item_desc AS ItemDesc
    , qty_requested AS QtyRequested
    , qty_shipped AS QtyShipped
    , unit_price AS UnitPrice
    , extended_price AS ExtendedPrice
    , SUM(extended_price) AS Total
    FROM P21.dbo.invoice_line AS a
    INNER JOIN P21.dbo.invoice_hdr AS b ON a.invoice_no = b.invoice_no
```

I know this can be done in excel easily, but can it be done in SQL easily?

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? sql server ? mysql

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: The error message really can't be more clear what the problem is.

Comment: 'I am using SQL Server Management Studio' - is a tool generally for sql-server - you should be clearer on what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: I updated the picture with the error message.

Comment: Do you want to do a query only or an update?

Comment: A query only. I want it to sum all of 'extended_price' but only as 1 number. Not repeated for every row in the query.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20are%20harder%20to%20read,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.

Comment: Thank you for that information @SeanLange , I will make sure any future questions are to the desired format.

Comment: @TriiKyPandas I'm very confused. What would you like in the next rows if you only want the sum once and not for each row? Somehow it doesn't make sense, so what's the goal? ... In your case, you are using aggregation and you are missing the GROUP BY clause. But I have a feeling you want something else.

Comment: @Cesc I updated the picture of the expected outcome

Comment: The desired output is possible but is really silly. Getting a sum of all the rows like that is almost always better in the front end, not directly from the query. You could do it but it would be a kludge. You would need to define the order of rows (there isn't one in your query), then do a subquery to get the sum and finally use ROW_NUMBER to only display the value of that subquery on the first row.

Comment: @SeanLange I honestly kind of figured that is was going to be burdensome to do something like that automatically in a query. But thank you all for the information.

Answer (score 0):

You could do smth like that:

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT 'a' AS [name], 1 as n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b', 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c', 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd', 2
),
cte1 AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [name]) AS rn, *
    FROM cte
)

SELECT [name], n, summ 
FROM cte1 c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS rn, SUM(n) AS summ
    FROM cte
) AS s
ON c.rn = s.rn
```

I used the sample cte above, but I think, you will get the idea

Edited:

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY customer_id)
    , customer_id AS CustomerID
    , invoice_date AS InvoiceDate
    , item_desc AS ItemDesc
    , qty_requested AS QtyRequested
    , qty_shipped AS QtyShipped
    , unit_price AS UnitPrice
    , extended_price AS ExtendedPrice
    FROM P21.dbo.invoice_line AS a
    INNER JOIN P21.dbo.invoice_hdr AS b ON a.invoice_no = b.invoice_no
)

SELECT [columns_you_need]
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS rn, SUM(extended_price) AS total
    FROM cte
) AS t
ON c.rn = t.rn
```

Comment: How would I convert this to my existing code?

Comment: @TriiKyPandas, check my edited answer